# RSpec testing two similar Models - one causes errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

The application has two similar models, Currency and Drills, which I test using RSpec and Factory Girl in identical manner but the Drill model has errors.

Drill Model

```
class Drill < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
  before_validation :clean_data
  def clean_data
    # trim whitespace from beginning and end of string attributes
    attribute_names.each do |name|
      if send(name).respond_to?(:strip)
        send("#{name}=", send(name).strip)
      end
   end
  end

  belongs_to :basin
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :sub_basin_structure
  has_many :drill_interests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :overriding_royalty_interests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, through: :drill_interests
  has_many :exchanges, through: :drill_interests
  has_many :resource_estimations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :company_listings, through: :companies
  has_many :evaluation_assumptions, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :stake, dependent: :destroy

 validates_uniqueness_of :name, message: "This drill name should be unique"
 validates :name, :country_id, :state_id, :basin_id, 
    :longitude, :latitude, presence: true
```

Spec/factoriesdrill.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :drill do 
    name "Drill007"
    association :basin
    association :state
    association :country
    association :sub_basin_structure
    latitude  '7 deg 7\' 7.7\" W'    # 7 deg 7' 7.7" W
    longitude '3 deg 3\' 3.3\" N'    # 3 deg 3' 3.3" N
  end
end
```

spec/model/drill_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Drill do

  it "Drill - has a valid factory" do
     expect(build(:drill)).to be_valid
  end

  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name) }
  it { should validate_presence_of :name }
  it { should validate_presence_of :basin_id }
  ...
```

Which produces errors as per below

```
Failures:



 1) Drill Drill - has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: expect(build(:drill)).to be_valid
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Name has already been taken
     # ./spec/model/drill_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Drill should require case sensitive unique value for name
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name) }
       Expected errors to include "has already been taken" when name is set to "a", got errors: ["This drill name should be unique (attribute: \"name\", value: \"a\")", "can't be blank (attribute: \"country_id\", value: nil)", "can't be blank (attribute: \"state_id\", value: nil)", "can't be blank (attribute: \"basin_id\", value: nil)", "can't be blank (attribute: \"longitude\", value: nil)", "can't be blank (attribute: \"latitude\", value: nil)"]
     # ./spec/model/drill_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.41 seconds (files took 4.17 seconds to load)
101 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/model/drill_spec.rb:5 # Drill Drill - has a valid factory
rspec ./spec/model/drill_spec.rb:9 # Drill should require case sensitive unique value for name
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'rubygems'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  DatabaseCleaner.start

  # Include Factory Girl syntax to simplify calls to factories
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  FactoryGirl.reload
```

Comment: Are you sure this factory is being called at all? The error says that 'a' is the name attribute when you defined Drill007 in your factory. Check if you have other factory somewhere initializing Drill. Also, check if your database is being cleaned (do you use the command to clean the database?)

Comment: Also I believe you can use validates :name, :country, :state, :basin ... without the '_id' cause Rails knows what u're talking about.

Comment: Thank Tiago I havelooked at your comments nad been busy checking ..

Comment: Have added spec_helper.rb.  I think I am cleaning database.  I can't figure out why it looks like it is trying toset Drills name to a

Comment: that's part of the validation spec - it will create one named 'a', and then try to create another one with the same name to make sure it's invalid.